# Proof of "Singular values of a normal matrix are the absolute values of its eigenvalues"

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I want a simple proof of this fact using only definitions and basic facts. I've searched for it for some time and I couldn't find a satisfying proof. So I attempted to do it myself.

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ and $A^H$ be conjugate transpose of $A$. Let $A$ be normal, i.e. $A A^H = A^H A$. The singular values of $A$ are defined as $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ such that

$$ \begin{align*}
A v &= \sigma u \\
A^H u &= \sigma v
\end{align*} $$

where $u^H u = v^H v = 1$. $u$ and $v$ are called left and right singular vectors respectively.

Now multiplying the first equation with $A^H$ and the second equation with $A$ from the left we obtain
$$ \begin{align*}
A^H A v &= \sigma A^H u = \sigma^2 v \\
A A^H u &= \sigma A v = \sigma^2 u
\end{align*} $$

Since $A$ is normal we obtain
$$ \begin{align*}
A A^H v &= \sigma^2 v \\
A A^H u &= \sigma^2 u
\end{align*} $$

<strike>I believe we can conclude that either $u=v$ or $u=-v$ if singular values are distinct. So by the definition we can see that either $\lambda=\sigma$ or $\lambda=-\sigma$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$. So $\sigma = | \lambda |$.</strike>

**Edit:** As @levap pointed out we can only conclude that $u = e^{i \theta} v, \theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$. Then we see that

$$ \begin{align*}
Av &= \sigma e^{i \theta} v \\
A^H v &= \sigma e^{-i \theta} v
\end{align*} $$

So, we can say that $\lambda = \sigma e^{i \theta}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Also, by the lemma given below $\sigma^2 \geq 0$, so $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and we can always select $\sigma \geq 0$ (using $-u$ in the definition if $\sigma \leq 0$). Therefore, we can conclude that $\sigma = |\lambda|$. Also, $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^H$ with $\bar{\lambda}$.

**Lemma.** Eigenvalues of $AA^H$ are real and non-negative.

*Proof.* $0 \leq \lVert A^H v \rVert_2 = v^H A A^H v = \sigma^2 v^H v = \sigma^2$.

What happens if singular values are not distinct?

Answer (score 8):

Since you work over $\mathbb{C}$, if the singular values are distinct you can only conclude that $u = e^{i\theta}v$ but this is enough.

If the singular values are not distinct, I doubt you'll find a "completely elementary" proof which avoids something like the spectral theorem as you need to know something about the eigenvalues of $AA^H$ and their relation to the eigenvalues of $A$.

Using the spectral theorem, I can offer the following argument. If $A$ is normal and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A^H$ with eigenvalue $\overline{\lambda}$. Denote the eigenvalues of $A$ by $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. Since $A$ is diagonalizable, we can choose a basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ with $Av_i =\lambda_i$. Then we have

$$ AA^H(v_i) = A(\overline{\lambda_i} v_i) = \lambda_i \overline{\lambda_i} v_i = |\lambda_i|^2 v_i $$

which shows that the eigenvalues of $AA^H$ are $|\lambda_1|^2, \ldots, |\lambda_n|^2$. Since you have shown that $\sigma^2$ is an eigenvalue of $AA^H$, we have $\sigma = |\lambda_i|$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've edited my question with your feedback. But diagonalizability of $A$ doesn't imply that the eigenvalues of $AA^H$ are $|\lambda_1|^2, \ldots, |\lambda_n|^2$. Take for example $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: It's not only the diagonalizability but also the fact that $A$ is normal and thus eigenvectors of $A$ are also eigenvectors of $A^H$. If $Av_i = \lambda_i$ then $AA^H(v_i) = A(\overline{\lambda_i}v_i) = \lambda_i \overline{\lambda_i} v_i = |\lambda_i|^2 v_i$.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect this point.

Comment: So proving that a left eigenvector of a normal matrix is also a right eigenvector is enough to conclude my question. In fact I proved it in my question for the distinct singular values case. Do you have any idea what can be done when the singular values are non-distinct?

Comment: It's not true that a left eigenvector of a normal matrix is also a right eigenvector. What is true is that if $v$ is a left eigenvector then $v^H$ is a right eigenevctor. To see this, note that if $vA = \lambda v$ then $A^H v^H = \overline{\lambda} v^H$ but since $A$ is normal, this implies that $v^H$ is also an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: "If $A$ is normal and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $A^H$ with eigenvalue $\bar{\lambda}$". Isn't it equivalent to "a left eigenvector of a normal matrix is also a right eigenvector" since $A^H v = \bar{\lambda} v$ implies $v^H A = \lambda v^H$? I'm assuming all vectors are column, so what I meant by left eigenvector is $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $v^H A = \lambda v^H$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent and can be proved directly from the definition of a normal matrix without any spectral theorem (in fact, it is usually a step in proving the spectral theorem) but I'm not sure how it solves your problem.

Comment: How can it be proven directly, can you elaborate on that? Also, since you showed that $\sigma = |\lambda|$ in your answer, why doesn't it solve my problem? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: My answer relied both on the fact that $A$ is diagonalizable and on the fact that eigenvectors of $A$ associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ are also eigenvectors of $A^H$ associated to $\overline{\lambda}$. I don't see how one can answer your problem using only the second part.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is normal, we can use spectral decomposition to get $A=UDU^*$ where $D$ is diagonal and $U$ is unitary. However the diagonal entries of $D$ may not be real and non-negative. We write the polar form of each diagonal entry $d_j$ of $D$ as $d_j = r_j e^{i \theta_j}$ for $j=1, \dots, n$, where $r_j \ge 0$. Then we see that

$$
A=UDU^*=U \text{diag}(e^{i \theta_1}, \dots, e^{i \theta_n}) \text{diag}(r_1, \dots, r_n) U^*
$$

is an SVD of $A$, where one can verify that

$$
U \text{diag}(e^{i \theta_1}, \dots, e^{i \theta_n})
$$

is a unitary matrix. Therefore the singular values of $A$ are $r_j = |d_j|$ for $j=1, \dots, n$.

This solution comes from Nathaniel Johnston's YouTube [course](https://youtu.be/8x67QZAvXaM?si=Z94H_J3Jtpk8mJbo&t=784).