# How to prove: if singular values equal the absolute values of eigenvalues then A is normal

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, singular-values

Another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551300/proof-of-singular-values-of-a-normal-matrix-are-the-absolute-values-of-its-eige) shows that if $A$ is normal that $|\lambda_i|=\sigma_i$ but how does one show the converse?

Comment: For anyone looking for a reference, this characterization of normality is Condition 57 in Grone, Johnson, Sa, and Wolkowicz, _Normal Matrices_, Linear algebra and its applications 87: 213–225 (1987).