# What's the singular value of a symmetric matrix plus identy matrix? $A+\lambda I$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, singular-values, matrix-analysis

Suppose, we know the singular values of a symmetric matrix $A$ as $\{\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_n\}$. What is the singular values of the matrix $A+\lambda I$?

Comment: $\lambda$ and $A_{ij}$ are real numbers?

Comment: If $A$ is real symmetric, its eigenvalues will be $\pm\sigma_1,\ldots,\pm\sigma_n$ (where the signs are not known). Hence the eigenvalues of $A+\lambda I$ are $\pm\sigma_i+\lambda$ and its singular values are $|\pm\sigma_i+\lambda|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A^*A=AA^*$ is a normal $n \times n$ complex matrix, then it is diagonalizable, and its singular values has the form $\sigma_i=|\alpha_i|$, where $\alpha_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, to $i=1,\,2,\,\ldots,\, n$.

If you fix a complex number $\lambda$, then you can verify that $\alpha_i+\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A+\lambda I$, to $i=1,\,2,\,\ldots,\, n$.

You can also verify that $A+\lambda I$ is also a normal matriz, and $|\alpha_i+\lambda|$, to $i=1,\,2,\,\ldots,\, n$, are its singular values.

Please see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551300/proof-of-singular-values-of-a-normal-matrix-are-the-absolute-values-of-its-eige), or find more on SearchOnMath.